# install scipy package via pycharm in windows 10 64 bit - python 3.5

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip, python-3.5

In PyCharm a "Python-IDE" in my **window 10 64 bit**, I want to install "Scipy".

First of all in {Pycharm -> File -> Settings -> interpreter} I chose C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe then I installed pip - matplotlib - numpy and labpack. Now I want to install scipy package but I got this error.

How can I solve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have an installation of numpy that was not compiled with LAPACK.

You can get a pre-compiled version from [Christopher Gohkle's "Python Extension Packages For Windows"](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) page, under `numpy-1.11.2+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl`. Then just run

```
pip install --user numpy-1.11.2+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl --upgrade
```

You should then try installing scipy again