# Unresolved reference "sklearn" in Python while importing GaussianNB

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to execute the following statements in PyCharm on Windows. I get the error message in the 4th line importing GaussianNB - sklearn: Unresolved Reference. Is there any package needed to be included or some other way to resolve this?

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
Y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X, Y)
print(clf.predict([[-0.8, -1]]))
```

Comment: Does your code run or not? Anyway, this is almost certainly a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725519/pycharm-shows-unresolved-references-error-for-valid-code)

Comment: No, the code is not running. It is showing the error - Unresolved Reference at sklearn and GaussianNB.

Comment: what version of python and sklearn are you using? have you tried updating to current sklearn?

Comment: Python: 3.6.2121.1013; PyCharm 2017.1.5; PIP:9.0.1; scikit-learn: 0.19b2; sklearn: 0.0.

Comment: @PSNayak that is not a Python error, that is your IDE giving you a warning.

Comment: This is the error I am getting after running the code:                  
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PN/Python/MLGoogle/ML1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

Comment: You need scipy to run Sklearn. On the [installation page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) it is specifically listed as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment it seems that SciPy module is missing.

After installing `scipy` the error should not appear.

The most common scipy - pycharm installation problems have been answered here (just in case that you get any error while trying to install `scipy`)

[See here 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663601/regarding-installing-scipy-from-pycharm)

[See here 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217173/install-scipy-package-via-pycharm-in-windows-10-64-bit-python-3-5)